# Play migration to 2.4.0 giving sbt.IncompatiblePluginsException: Binary incompatibility in plugins

Tags: playframework, sbt, playframework-2.4

I have a project that has been migrated from play 2.2.1 to play 2.3.0 now when i try to migrate that to play 2.4.0, i am getting the below error.

```
[error] sbt.IncompatiblePluginsException: Binary incompatibility in plugins dete
cted.
[error] Note that conflicts were resolved for some dependencies:
[error]         org.apache.commons:commons-compress
[error]         org.tukaani:xz
[error]         com.google.guava:guava
[error]         com.typesafe:config
[error]         org.slf4j:slf4j-api
[error]         org.fusesource.leveldbjni:leveldbjni
[error]         com.typesafe:jse_2.10
[error]         com.typesafe.sbt:sbt-js-engine
[error]         com.typesafe.sbt:sbt-web
[error]         org.javassist:javassist


I am not able to resolve it.
```

Comment: Run the command again and post the whole output. Also, it would be useful if you post your `build.sbt`, `project/plugins.sbt` and `project/build.properties` files.

Comment: Have you followed migration guide? Have you removed all `target`? `find . -name target/ | xargs rm -Rf`